# How do I output something in Rhino?

Tags: javascript, linux, rhino

I'm looking for the javascript equivalent of Python2.x's `print "hi"`.
I'm working with the Rhino javascript interpreter in the ubuntu terminal.
When I type:

```
document.write{"hi"}
```

I get the error that 'document' is not defined.

Comment: From the CLI is it not just print('hi');

Comment: Advice: use node instead of rhino (it has for starters a better implemented prompt). You can just run a js file like this: `node myfile.js`. If you want to print in a node script just use `console.log` like in the browser.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have any built in methods to provide output. Scripts have to depend on features provided by the host environment for that.

`document` is an object that is available in web browsers, but not in Rhino. Even if it was available, `document.write` is a function. You use `()` to call a function, not `{}`.

Rhino provides a [`print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell#print%28.5Bexpr_....5D%29) function.

```
print("hi");
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have access to the 'document' object - as the one I think you're referring to is only available when javascript is run in the browser.

Also, use normal brackets rather than curly brackets to invoke functions.

Just try:

```
print('Hello, world!')
```